# FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange in Avalonia UI?

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui

When declaring a property in WPF, you can set metadata like this

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsStopVisibleProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsStopVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(MediaPlayer),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange));
```

In Avalonia UI, there is no parameter to set metadata

```
public static readonly StyledProperty<bool> IsStopVisibleProperty = 
    AvaloniaProperty.Register<MediaPlayer, bool>(nameof(IsStopVisible), true);
```

What's the equivalent of FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to make a property affect the arrange of the control itself is to add a call to [`AffectsArrange`](http://reference.avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Layout/Layoutable/C845D3DF) in your control's static constructor:

```cs
static MediaPlayer()
{
    AffectsArrange(IsStopVisibleProperty);
}
```

However this is the equivalent of WPF's `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange` flag, not `AffectsParentArrange`. It is quite unusual for a control's property to directly affect the parent control's arrange - the scenario for `AffectsParentArrange` is usually limited to attached properties on `Panel` controls. Because of this, Avalonia's [`AffectsParentArrange`](http://reference.avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Controls/Panel/E59E2D81) is a protected method on `Panel` so will probably be unavailable in your control.

However if you're *sure* that you need to invalidate the parent's arrange on property change, probably the best way to do this would be to simply invalidate the parent arrange in `OnPropertyChanged`:

```cs
        protected override void OnPropertyChanged<T>(AvaloniaPropertyChangedEventArgs<T> change)
        {
            if (change.Property == IsStopVisibleProperty)
            {
                ((Control)Parent)?.InvalidateArrange();
            }

            base.OnPropertyChanged(change);
        }
```